# Customer logged in report on magento2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, reports, customer-session

Want to have a report to know each customer how many times logged in my Magento 2.3 site.
If customer A comes 3 times in a day it should count just once not 3.
I want to sort them by day, a weak, month too. it just needs for reporting

Comment: Have you looked at reporting extensions? This isn't a small task.

Comment: Yes i want to just log theme all